# Repeating function call until we'll get non-empty Option result in Scala

Tags: scala, loops

A very newbie question in Scala - how do I do "repeat function until something is returned meets my criteria" in Scala?

Given that I have a function that I'd like to call until it returns the result, for example, defined like that:

```
def tryToGetResult: Option[MysteriousResult]
```

I've come up with this solution, but I really feel that it *is* ugly:

```
var res: Option[MysteriousResult] = None
do {
  res = tryToGetResult
} while (res.isEmpty)
doSomethingWith(res.get)
```

or, equivalently ugly:

```
var res: Option[MysteriousResult] = None
while (res.isEmpty) {
  res = tryToGetResult
}
doSomethingWith(res.get)
```

I really feel like there is a solution without `var` and without so much hassle around manual checking whether `Option` is empty or not.

For comparison, Java alternative that I see seems to be much cleaner here:

```
MysteriousResult tryToGetResult(); // returns null if no result yet

MysteriousResult res;
while ((res = tryToGetResult()) == null);
doSomethingWith(res);
```

To add insult to injury, if we don't need to `doSomethingWith(res)` and we just need to return it from this function, Scala vs Java looks like that:

#### Scala

```
def getResult: MysteriousResult = {
  var res: Option[MysteriousResult] = None
  do {
    res = tryToGetResult
  } while (res.isEmpty)
  res.get
}
```

#### Java

```
MysteriousResult getResult() {
    while (true) {
        MysteriousResult res = tryToGetResult();
        if (res != null)  return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Stream`'s `continually` method to do precisely this:

```
val res = Stream.continually(tryToGetResult).flatMap(_.toStream).head
```

Or (possibly more clearly):

```
val res = Stream.continually(tryToGetResult).dropWhile(!_.isDefined).head
```

One advantage of this approach over explicit recursion (besides the concision) is that it's much easier to tinker with. Say for example that we decided that we only wanted to try to get the result a thousand times. If a value turns up before then, we want it wrapped in a `Some`, and if not we want a `None`. We just add a few characters to our code above:

```
Stream.continually(tryToGetResult).take(1000).flatMap(_.toStream).headOption
```

And we have what we want. (Note that the `Stream` is lazy, so even though the `take(1000)` is there, if a value turns up after three calls to `tryToGetResult`, it will only be called three times.)

Comment: Technically, it spawns additional objects and potenially a huge list of `None`s, if we'll try to get result myriads of times, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this is much better than my solution

Comment: There's an almost identical `continually` on `Iterator` that doesn't hold onto its results, if that turns out to be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Performing side effects like this make me die a little inside, but how about this?

```
scala> import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.annotation.tailrec

scala> @tailrec
     | def lookupUntilDefined[A](f: => Option[A]): A = f match {
     |   case Some(a) => a
     |   case None => lookupUntilDefined(f)
     | }
lookupUntilDefined: [A](f: => Option[A])A
```

Then call it like this

```
scala> def tryToGetResult(): Option[Int] = Some(10)
tryToGetResult: ()Option[Int]

scala> lookupUntilDefined(tryToGetResult())
res0: Int = 10
```

You may want to give `lookupUntilDefined` an additional parameter so it can stop eventually in case f is never defined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Are you sure that this recursion would be accepted for tail recursion optimization? As far as I can see from Erlang's point of view, it will require to store every `None` instance in a call stack.

Comment: The REPL would have given a warning if it was not `tailrec` optimizable. There would be cleaner ways to implement this without the match that are unfortunately not `tailrec` optimizable. (Ignoring `tailrec` non-warning bug found by @PrecogIO here)